# upstart starts python script but it behaves unexpectedly

Tags: python, ubuntu, upstart

The program works when started by `cron` or from the shell. But when started by `upstart`, it seems to loop indefinitely.

The scripts and the files they use are in the `/home/user/` directory, and are owned by `user`, and all have `777` permissions.

**The upstart .conf file:**

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

kill signal SIGHUP
# reload signal SIGHUP
respawn

exec python /home/user/Documents/init.py -b 600
```

Comment: It seems, that the question belongs to either [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: the following things are going to be different depending on the way you run the program: `CWD`, `environment`, `uid`. So check them all in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`upstart` executes commands as root by default. But the user can be specified: https://askubuntu.com/questions/87671/how-do-i-start-jobs-as-a-non-privileged-user-in-upstart.

But the script was programmed with `user` specific variables and a dependency to a specific directory.

init.py had this line:

```
self.d_root = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'Documents','records')
```

I changed it to this and it worked:

```
self.d_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

But I think the proper fix is to add this line to the `.conf` file:

```
setuid username
```